# Is it possible to train a new cascade classifier from existing xml file

Tags: cascade, haar-classifier

I am currently using opencv haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml as face detector. When I am testing it, it failed to find the face for some images. I am wondering if it is possible to train a new classifier from the current version by adding those failures?

Answer (score 0):

You have to train with your new dataset :(